# TypeScript doesn't see defaultProps for functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know this problem has been tackled in here, but I can't seem to find a solution that would help me.

My code is as follows:

```
import * as React from "react";
import inject from "react-jss";

import styles from "./index.styles";

import * as JSS from "jss";

type Colors = "Red" | "White";

interface Props {
  onClick: () => void;
  disabled: boolean;
  classes: JSS.Classes;
  color: Colors;
}

const Button: React.StatelessComponent<Props> = (props): React.ReactElement<any> => {
  const { children, onClick, classes, disabled, color } = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled} className={[classes.Main, classes[color]].join(" ")}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  color: "Red",
  disabled: false,
  onClick: () => false,
};

export default inject(styles)(Button);
```

All seems good, but when I use this component without either `color` or `onClick` props, I am getting an error:

> Error:(14, 8) TS2322: Type '{ children: string; onClick: () => void;
>   disabled: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick'.   Property 'color' is missing in type '{ children:
>   string; onClick: () => void; disabled: boolean; }'.

What can I do? I'm on TS3.1.1.

Comment: What version of react and react definitions are you using ?

Comment: I think it might be a bug, if I declare `declare const Button: React.ComponentClass<Props> & { defaultProps: typeof defaultProps }` it works, if I declare `declare const Button: React.StatelessComponent<Props> & { defaultProps: typeof defaultProps }` it does not work, I would expect defaultprops to be picked up in both casses

Comment: For a direct usage `<Button/>`, the stateless component is working for me using the current `master` of TypeScript, so the bug seems to have been fixed.  However, the `inject` HOC may not be using `JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes`; I haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen it's a bug fixed in 3.2 does not work on 3.1 ..

Comment: Oops, duplicate work again.  I'd like a better way to avoid it on Stack Overflow, but my sense is that trying to bring it up on meta won't be worth my energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27425) on 3.1. The code below works on 3.2 (at moment unreleased, you can install using `npm install typescript@next`

```
interface Props {
  onClick: () => void;
  disabled: boolean;
  classes: string;
  color: string;
}
type StatelessComponentArgs<T> = T & { children?: React.ReactNode } // reusable type for the arguments of a stateless compontent
const Button = (props: StatelessComponentArgs<Props>): React.ReactElement<any> => {
  const { children, onClick, classes, disabled, color } = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled} >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  color: "Red",
  disabled: false,
  onClick: () => false,
};

let d = <Button classes="" color="" onClick={() => { }} disabled={false}></Button>
let d3 = <Button classes="" color="" onClick={() => { }} ></Button>
```

There is also an issue with your code. If you explicitly type `Button` as a `React.StatelessComponent<Props>` `defaultProps` will implicitly be `Partial<Props>` regardless of what you assign to it. You need to let the compiler infer the type of `defaultProps` as in the sample above.

Comment: Thanks Titian! But do I really have to include definition of `children`? Shouldn't this be inherited/extended from somewhere? Seems kinda tedious.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski The usual way is to use as you have the type directly on  the variable `const Button: React.StatelessComponent<Props>`. You could easily create a helper type `type StatelessComponentArgs<T> = T & { children?: React.ReactNode }` and use that as an argument. I'll edit the answer to and this.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the `defaultProps` to work, the actual type of your `defaultProps` object has to be present on the the type of `Button`.  Since TypeScript 3.1, [you can declare a function and assign to its properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#properties-declarations-on-functions) and the assigned properties will be automatically added to the function's type, *unless* you have already annotated a type for the function, as you have.  If I remove the type annotation and then make the necessary changes for the code to work (specify the type of the `props` parameter and add a type assertion to the default `color` to stop it from widening), then I'm able to call the component successfully:

```
const Button = (props: Props & { children?: React.ReactNode }): React.ReactElement<any> => {
  const { children, onClick, classes, disabled, color } = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled} className={[classes.Main, classes[color]].join(" ")}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
Button.defaultProps = {
  color: "Red" as Colors,
  disabled: false,
  onClick: () => false,
};

const WrappedButton = inject(styles)(Button);
<WrappedButton/>;
```

An alternative to removing the type annotation is to use a custom interface that includes the type of your `defaultProps` object, as I believe Titian Cernicova-Dragomir was thinking:

```
interface Props {
  onClick: () => void;
  disabled: boolean;
  classes: JSS.Classes;
  color: Colors;
  // Something is broken with `inject` without this.
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const buttonDefaultProps = {
  color: "Red" as Colors,
  disabled: false,
  onClick: () => false,
};
interface ButtonSFC extends React.SFC<Props> {
  defaultProps: typeof buttonDefaultProps;
}

const Button: ButtonSFC = (props): React.ReactElement<any> => {
  const { children, onClick, classes, disabled, color } = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled} className={[classes.Main, classes[color]].join(" ")}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
Button.defaultProps = buttonDefaultProps;

const WrappedButton = inject(styles)(Button);
<WrappedButton/>;
```

Note that `<Button/>` gives an error in TypeScript 3.1: it seems that the `defaultProps` are not being honored for stateless function components.  In the current `master` version of TypeScript, this problem no longer occurs (so I don't think it's worth investigating) (edit: Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer has the link to the bug report), but there's a different problem: `<WrappedButton/>` gives an error because support for calling `React.ComponentType` has been [temporarily removed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27948).  Work on a fix for that is in progress.  Hopefully, for the moment, as long as you don't need to call `Button` directly, you can stay on TypeScript 3.1.